# Number format in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

How to keep number format as is in excel if the number length is more than 15.
I see that any number above lenght 15 is getting converted to scientific format and finding difficult to compare using any formula.

Suggest if anyone has solution to avoid this  in excel 2010.

Thanks
Joshi

Answer (score 1):

Right click the cell, choose Format Cell, then select Special and choose "0". If it isn't there you can type it in manually. You can also choose "Number" and change "Decimal Places" to 0 if you do not want them. [image]